# How to extract a substring of a URL with regex

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, extract

Working with some unstructured data and hoping to extract utm_campaign names from URLs. Here's an example of one URL. I'd like to extract the name following "utm_campaign=" but before "&utm_source" each time. How can I do this with regex?

```
https://data.io/?utm_campaign=branded&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=data&gclid=CjwKCAjwiuuRBhBvEiwAFXKaNGwDI2MaPLQpb9duvQZ2XeOA4vpk7FuBTqhYiJ2ysnirdUh8SZ6-zxoC4VYQAvD_BwE
```

I've tried various regex functions, for instance:

```
regexp_substr(get_path(event_properties, 'url'), '(\[A-Za-z\_-\]\*)-utm_campaign')
```

Comment: Did you tried parse_url - it will give json output from which you can extract as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Easier done with `parse_url`

```
select parse_url(your_url):parameters:"utm_campaign"::string
```

Or you can divide and conquer using `split_part`

```
select split_part(split_part(your_url,'utm_campaign=',-1),'&',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT regexp_substr(get_path(event_properties, 'url'), '\\b+[-utm_campaign=](\\w+)&\\b+', 1, 1, 'e', 1)
```

Reference: [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html)

Comment: thank you, michael! this did the trick